# Laplace Transform of a Truncated Random Variable

Tags: probability, laplace-transform

Let $B$ be a random variable, and $S=\mbox{min}(1,B)$. Can you help
me see why the laplace stieltjes transform of $S$ is given by $$
E[e^{-\alpha S}]=1-\alpha\int_{0}^{1}e^{-\alpha y}P(B\geq y)dy$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the integrated form (with respect to the distribution of $B$) of the equality
$$
1-\mathrm e^{-\alpha\min\{1,x\}}=\int_0^1\alpha\mathrm e^{-\alpha y}\,[x\geqslant y]\,\mathrm dy,
$$
valid for every $x\geqslant0$. To prove the equality holds, note that the RHS is
$$
\int_0^{\min\{1,x\}}\alpha\mathrm e^{-\alpha y}\,\mathrm dy=\left[-\mathrm e^{-\alpha y}\right]_{y=0}^{y=\min\{1,x\}}=1-\mathrm e^{-\alpha\min\{1,x\}}.
$$